# How to write Rust Tower middleware for authentication in a REST API

Tags: rust, swagger, openapi

**TL;DR: I need an example from someone who knows the Rust/Swagger generated server code on how to write a middleware layer for authentication.**

I've been working on a REST API built from an OpenApi spec (Swagger-file) with
Rust, and I want to implement some authentication with a middleware layer.

I have spec file that lists a number of services, that are all secured with an
API key. Whenever a service is called, I would like to peek at the HTTP request,
before running the actual service.

I want to validate the API key, and possibly do some back-channel server calls.
If the API key checks out, I want to run the actual service code, but if it doesn't,
I want to return a custom HTTP response.

The Rust generator uses a Hyper server, and generates some middleware in the form
of Tower services. I thought it would be a picnic to replace the "AllowAll"
middleware with one of my own making, but so far, I have had no success.

I think I understand how Tower services are supposed to work, but the ones generated
by the Swagger generator are a little more complex, to say the least, and they take
the form of a two step process, where one middleware  generates another service and
wraps that, which then in turn wraps the preciously added middleware.

Long story short, I need some help from more experienced Rustaceans :)

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have a spec, `middleware.yaml` like this:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Middleware Test
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      operationId: test
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Ok
      security:
        - api_key: []
components:
  securitySchemes:
    api_key:
      type: apiKey
      name: api_key
      in: header
```

I generate a server project using the `openapi-generator-cli` tool:

```bash
npx --yes @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    --generate-alias-as-model \
    --api-package middleware \
    --package-name middleware \
    -g rust-server \
    -i middleware.yaml
```

This generates a library crate that I can then use in my own code. For the sake
of simplicity, we can look at the example server, generated by the tool
(in `examples/server/server.rs`). The interesting part is the function that
creates the Hyper server:

```rust
pub async fn create(addr: &str) {
    let addr = addr.parse().expect("Failed to parse bind address");

    let server = Server::new();
    let service = middleware::server::MakeService::new(server);
    let service = swagger::auth::MakeAllowAllAuthenticator::new(service, "cosmo");
    let service = middleware::server::context::MakeAddContext::<_, EmptyContext>::new(service);
    
    hyper::server::Server::bind(&addr).serve(service).await.unwrap()
}
```

It creates an implementation of the API (`Server::new()`), and wraps it in three services.

My problem is, that the combination of two-tiered wrappers (i.e. `MakeAllowAllAuthenticator`
is a wrapper for an internal `AllowAllAuthenticator` which in turns wraps the previous
`MakeService` that wraps a `Service`) and the Rust-Swagger concept of the context which is
not a plain struct but a set of trait bounds that hides a seemingly dynamic implementation.

This creates a very complex set of boundary requirements.

So, I'm hoping I'm not the only one using the Rust/Swagger generator, and that someone can
point me at an example of a middleware implementation, in the expected two service format
(`MakeFoo`/`Foo`) that inspects the raw HTTP body, and possibly returns an early result,
instead of proceeding with the chain.

Like I said, the short term purpose is to plug in my authentication code, but in the long term
I would like to clean up my code by moving some things I do in every service method into the
context that is built by the `create` method.

Comment: I just want to say, that I know I can get the API key header value from the `Option<AuthData>` in the Swagger context, but I don't want to add code to every service method implementation that looks for it, and decides what to do in each place. That's what I'm doing for now, and it's a brittle mess.

Comment: Same situation, but I do not know how to get the headers (Bearer token in my case). I am kind of new to Rust but it seems C (Context) only implements Has<XSpanIdString> + Has<Option<Authorization>> trait and not Has<XSpanIdString> + Has<Option<AuthData>>.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the proper way to handle it that is, writing an "CustomAuthenticator" and "MakeCustomAuthenticator" which implements the preferred authentication scheme, then the generated code is able to handle the proper authorization for each API, based on securityScheme definitions.